# How would you create stackable rectangles in Xamarin C# for iOS?

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a UIView that I want to fill with multiple rectangles stacked on top of each other horizontally at 100% width. They all need to have their own name and need to work for any iOS device regardless of size.

Here's a simple diagram showing what I would like to accomplish:

[image: Stacked rectangles]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Xamarin.Forms, this is achieved by using a `StackLayout`.

http://iosapi.xamarin.com/?link=T%3aXamarin.Forms.StackLayout

Comment: I went with StackLayout, would like to try using Grids next time.

Answer (score 3):

I find it difficult to control the exact sizes of StackLayouts if you're not sure of the size of your content.
If i need something to stay fixed size, i use Grids:

http://iosapi.xamarin.com/?link=T%3aXamarin.Forms.Grid

Comment: I upvoted you but gave Miguel the correct answer as I decided to go with StackLayout before I saw your post. Grids looks like it might have been easier to control in my situation so I'm definitely giving that a try next time. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend XibFree for this:
http://www.toptensoftware.com/xibfree/

They have a few great examples which covers these case as well:
http://www.toptensoftware.com/xibfree/example_2

http://www.toptensoftware.com/xibfree/example_1

If you would need any more help with XibFree feel free to ask anything in comment :)